# An asymptotic connection between nth prime number and prime counting function

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to prove an asymptotic between the nth prime number and the prime-counting function. Numerically it seems right but I don't know if every step is correct.
So here we go:
We know that
$$\pi(n)\sim\frac{n}{\log n} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad p_n \sim n\log n \qquad (n\rightarrow\infty).$$
The first statement can be rewritten as
$$\pi(n) \sim \frac{n\log n}{\log^2 n} \qquad (n\rightarrow\infty).$$
Now, is the next step valid?
$$\pi(n)\log^2 n\sim n\log n \qquad (n\rightarrow\infty).$$
If this step is valid we can continue and say that
$$\pi(n)\log^2 n\sim p_n \qquad (n\rightarrow\infty),$$
which is my desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the steps are justified. In general,
$$f(n) \sim g(n) \implies h(n) \cdot f(n) \sim h(n) \cdot g(n),$$
and in your case, you can just multiply the prime number theorem by $\log^2 n$ and substitute $p_n$ for  $n\log n$ (since $\sim$ is also transitive).

Just remember the definition of $f\sim g$, i.e., that $\lim\frac fg = 1$.